# Linux execute php file with arguments

Tags: linux, xargs

I have .php takes three parameters. For example: `./execute.php 11 111 111`
I have like list of data in text file with spacing. For example:

```
22 222 222
33 333 333
44 444 444
```

I was thinking for using xargs to pass in the arguements but its not working.
here is my try

```
cat raw.txt | xargs -I % ./execute.php %0 %1 %2
```

doesn't work, any idea?
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the following transcript, you are *not* handling the data correctly:

```
pax> printf '2 22 222\n3 33 333\n4 44 444\n' | xargs -I % echo %0 %1 %2
2 22 2220 2 22 2221 2 22 2222
3 33 3330 3 33 3331 3 33 3332
4 44 4440 4 44 4441 4 44 4442
```

Each `%` is giving you the entire line, and the digit following the `%` is just tacked on to the end.

To investigate, lets first create a fake processing file `proc.sh` (and `chmod 700` it so we can run it easily):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$# '$1' '$2' '$3'"
```

Even if you switch to `xargs -I % ./proc.sh %`, you'll find you get *one* argument with embedded spaces, not three individual arguments:

```
pax> vi proc.sh ; printf '2 22 222\n3 33 333\n4 44 444\n' | xargs -I % ./proc.sh %
1 '2 22 222' '' ''
1 '3 33 333' '' ''
1 '4 44 444' '' ''
```

---

The easiest solution is probably to switch to a `for read` loop, something like:

```
pax:~> printf '2 22 222\n3 33 333\n4 44 444\n' | while read p1 p2 p3 ; do ./proc.sh ${p1} ${p2} ${p3} ; done
3 '2' '22' '222'
3 '3' '33' '333'
3 '4' '44' '444'
```

You can see there the program is called with three arguments, you just have to adapt it to your own program:

```
while read p1 p2 p3 ; do ./proc.sh ${p1} ${p2} ${p3} ; done < raw.txt
```